# Spring mongodb query using regex

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I have a string field with value a,b,c,d,e i.e. {fld1:"a,b,c,d,e"}

I would like to check whether two input String is part of the fld1 or not

e.g.

```
    input result 
    ====  =======
    a,b = true
    a,e = true 
    b,f = false 
    e,b = true 
    100,g = false
```

Could you please let me know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use map reduce to achieve this. Check out this link
[How to search comma separated data in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30940908/how-to-search-comma-separated-data-in-mongodb)